# PHP Log-in with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, validation, authentication

im currently struggling to get my PHP log in to work. Iv used a separations of concerns to  structure my php.

Iv already set up in my database a Users table with id, username and password values.

I dont think that there is a problem connecting to my database as i've used the same code in other projects and it works there.

This is my user_repository.php:

```html
<?php
require_once "database.php";

function authenticate_user($username, $password, &$error) {

 $sql = "select * from Users where username= '${username}'";
 $sql .=" and password='{password}'";
 $result = query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows!=1) {

  $error = "Username or password was incroeect.";
  return null;

 }

return $result-> fetch_assoc();

}

function get_user_by_id($id, &$error) {

 $sql = "select * from Users where id={$id} limit 1;";
 $result = query($sql);

 return $result->fetch_assoc();



}

?>
```

This is my database.php:

```html
<?php

 define("SQLHOST", "localhost");
 define("SQLUSER", "b3006796");
 define("SQLDB", "b3006796_db3");
 define("SQLPASSWORD", "*******");

 function connect_to_database () {

  $mysqli = new mysqli(SQLHOST, SQLUSER, SQLPASSWORD, SQLDB);

  if($mysqli->connect_errno) {

   echo "failed to connect to mysql:  ".$mysqli->connect_errno;
   exit();


  }

  return $mysqli;
 }

 function query ($sql) {

  $mysqli = connect_to_database();

  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  if (!$result) {
   echo "failed to run query:  ".$mysqli->error;
   exit();



}

return $result;

}
?>
```

This is my index.php:

```html
<?php

 session_start();
 require_once "user_repository.php";

 $error = null;

 if (isset ($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
  $username = $_POST ["username"];
  $password = $_POST ["password"];


  // Get the assoc array for the user.
  $user = authenticate_user($username, $password, $error);

  //No error means valid password here.
  if (!$error) {
   $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $user['id'];
   header("location:account.php");
   exit();

  }


  }

?>

<html>
<head>
 <title> DIWA Login </title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>login</h1>
 <form method="post">
  Username:<input name="username"/>
  Password:<input name="password" type="password"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
  <?php if ($error);?>
  <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>

 </form?
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Account.php:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once "user_repository.php";

 $error = null;

 if (!isset($_SESSION["currentUser"])) {
 header ("Location: login.php");
 exit();
 }

 $user = get_user_by_id($_SESSION["currentUser"], $error);
 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
  <title> DIWA Account </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1> Account </h1>
  <p> User ID: <?php echo $user["id"]; ?></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: so what is your question

Comment: $sql .=" and password='{password}'"; - you omitted "$" - $password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that you cannot log in, then there is at least one bug:

```
`$sql .=" and password='{password}'";`
```

you omitted "$" at 'password', it should be

```
$sql .=" and password='{$password}'";
```

Also:

```
$sql = "select * from Users where username= '${username}'";
```

should be:

```
$sql = "select * from Users where username= '{$username}'";
```